# Firmware update on Dell Latitude 5510 fails with "missing signed bootloader for secure boot"

Tags: uefi, dell, firmware

Using Ubuntu 21.04, I'm trying to update the firmware on a Dell Latitude 5510. The command is `fwupdmgr update`, and it looks good to begin with.

I receive this message:

```
Upgrade available for System Firmware from 1.5.1 to 1.7.0
Latitude 5510 must remain plugged into a power source for the duration of the update to avoid damage. Continue with update? [Y|n]:
```

This goes well while the update is downloading and decompressing, but stops in the authenticating stage with this message:

```
missing signed bootloader for secure boot: /usr/libexec/fwupd/efi/fwupdx64.efi.signed cannot be found
```

I have seen similar questions both here and elsewhere, but no solution. I obviously don't understand this signing business, but still hope that someone here can assist.

Simple question: how can I sign the bootloader using only Ubuntu?

Comment: Is it an option for you to turn off secure boot? That's what I would recommend.

Comment: @sudodus That is indeed an option. I'll give it a go soon :)

Comment: @sudodus If I turn it off, will my existing Ubuntu still boot, or do I need to reinstall?

Comment: Ubuntu will definitely boot without secure boot, and I think Windows will boot too, but I am not sure (no Windows expert here) ;-)

Comment: @sudodus Sounds good to me! There is no windoze on this machine, so it should be a breeze then :D

Comment: @sudodus Playing with the UEFI worked! I found I could even keep secure boot on since there was another level beneath that, that controlled just the security for the boot loader! So secure boot is still on, but at a "lower level of security". And all the firmware has just been upgraded, the machine rebooted and here I am with a fresh, working system! You need to add an answer to my question I believe, to receive the bounty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn off secure boot. The signature is for secure boot, and you can turn it off during the firmware update.

Depending on the firmware you might or might not need to run the computer with secure boot off after that operation. I think it is OK to run the computer without secure boot.

Ubuntu has a license from Microsoft to sign its software for secure boot, but several Linux distros have no such license (and don't want it because it is not FOSS). Those distros must be run with secure boot turned off.

Answer (score 1):

Please go into your computer's BIOS and turn the secure boot off, then you will be able to boot into Ubuntu. Secure boot does little, especially for Linux users; it was made to prevent you/malware for removing Windows!